# ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined

Tags: webpack, phaser-framework

I have this src/index.html file:.

```
    <!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 1</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()    
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 
            'assets/dude.png',
            { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
    }

    function create ()
    {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }

    function update ()
    {
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this webpack.config.js file

```
    const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const config = {
  entry: './src/scripts/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader?name=/src/assets/[name].[ext]',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      'dist',
    ),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
    config.output.filename = 'main.bundle.js';
  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin());
    config.output.filename = 'main.[hash].bundle.js';
  }

  return config;
};
```

when I'm in the project root and type:

```
  npx webpack --mode development
```

It creates a dist/index.html file in the root of the project

I open the file with my web browser (firefox) and I get this output

[image]

It doesn't recognize the 'Phaser' command in the index.html file

Check this line in the index.html file:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

What's going on? How can I fix this? If you need more info just ask I'll expand so you can help.

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/space-shooter-game/tree/be96bd4e27af98cc6b355df3509a9409f051e825) is the repository in the feature branch I'm working at the time of the question

Answer (score 1):

Extract the javascript from the index.html file and create a .js file that gets imported into the html by webpack

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';

function preload() {
  this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
  this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
  this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
  this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
  this.load.spritesheet('dude',
    'assets/dude.png',
    { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
}

function update() {
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
    update,
  },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Check the first line of the .js file

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';
```